Remove [idb] synonym from [indexeddb]
The idb library is one of the most popular libraries for the IndexedDB API (if not the most popular), but it is currently a tag synonym for the API itself.
Some people do just refer to IndexedDB as IDB, but there are a significant number of questions that are referring to the library, and should be able to be tagged as such.
Recent examples:

IndexedDB across tabs: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open
How to move data from one store to another in indexedDB
top-level await in a module prevents `onload` from firing
Getting an error when adding a value to indexDB
Upgrading an indexeddb which is shared by a PWA and its service worker


Being a 3 letter tag, idb would be a bad tag to use since it's likely ambiguous, and after all, you yourself already have two different (albeit related) meanings.
So instead of removing the synonym, we should prefer an unambiguous tag name such as idb-library for the library instead.

I'd be okay with [idb] being a synonym of [idb-library]. Either way, the existing synonym should be removed.

I think we should only change where the synonym points to if the other tag ([[tag:idb-library]]) turns out to be more popular, from what I've seen in my searches that isn't the case though.
